# Excel Client Side to Server Side

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon.

The YMCA I work at is looking to move into a paperless setup at our membership services desks.  We will be using Adobe Sign to get documents signed which will then send .PDF files to a default email address.

I found a Client Side VBA script to automatically send attachments to a hard drive folder, but I am looking for assistance on how to change it to Server Side.

The Client Side VBA is:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "c:\temp\"
     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```

1. How can I get this Server Side, so it sends to a network folder?

Comment: Change the `saveFolder` string value to the network folder, including its IP e.g. `saveFolder = "\\00.0.00.000\ExampleNetworkFolderName\ExampleFolderName`

Comment: Will that work even if Outlook is closed?  As far as I was told, from the initial script used, Outlook has to be open.  Would it work if the VBA was on the exchange server itself?